# Where does the "0 down vote" in front of my comment come from?

Tags: support, comments

I'm pretty sure I didn't type "0 down vote" in front of [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56931/research-database-access-friction/56935#comment132777_56935):

[image]

Is this a feature to indicate that I commented but didn't down vote? Or did I lower-backside-dial this at some point?

I have no ways of exploring the comment's history.

Comment: I wondered about this when I saw it. I thought it was a subtle way of saying "would downvote but not enough to -1", or something. Maybe we should start using it... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the question history, it shows that text as having been present in the original comment. My guess is that when you copy/pasted the answer text, you selected the up/down vote arrows as well. When you copy/paste those, you'll see the number of downvotes in the text. Try it yourself.

Comment: Ah, that sounds plausible. I thought it might have been an attempt at addressing the much discussed feature of binding down votes to explaining comments.